# Left Joining Multiple Sets of Tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table of answers that lists possible answers for a given question.

```
possible_answer 
id question_id text
1  1           yes
2  1           no
3  2           red
4  2           blue
5  2           green
```

Then I have a table of answers that users have given

```
user_answer
id user_id answer_id 
1  10      1
2  10      3
3  11      1
4  11      4
5  12      2
6  12      5
```

I am trying to create a MySQL query that will show me the username, the user's answer for question 1 (could be null) and the user's answer for question 2 (could be null). I am getting stuck because I feel like I need to group multiple LEFT JOINS together, but I am getting output that gives me one of the answers, or the same answer in both columns.

Here's what I've got at this point:

```
SELECT u.name, pa1.text, pa2.text
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_answer ua1 ON u.id = ua1.user_id 
LEFT JOIN possible_answer pa1 ON ua1.answer_id = pa1.id AND pa1.question_id = 1
LEFT JOIN user_answer ua2 ON u.id = ua2.user_id 
LEFT JOIN possible_answer pa2 ON ua2.answer_id = pa2.id AND pa2.question_id = 2
GROUP BY u.id;
```

I am getting results such as:

```
username  pa1.text  pa2.text
user1     yes       NULL
user2     no        NULL
user3     NULL      blue
```

When I know that there are entries for both questions for the given user.

I have the `group by` in there because when I did not have `group by` I was getting results like this (which is sorta closer to the intended result) but they were not appearing to show any type of pattern:

```
username  pa1.text  pa2.text
    user1     yes       NULL
    user1     NULL      red
    user2     no        NULL
    user2     NULL      NULL
    user3     no        NULL
    user3     NULL      blue
```

Any thoughts would be very appreciated.

Comment: *Any thoughts?*  You're getting what you asked for.  user1 answered "YES" to question 1.  User1 had no answer to question 2 so NULL is being displayed becuase PA2.text is "No" but UA2.answer_ID is null for that text.  Thus you get NULL.  So if you're after a list of all questions, their possible answers and what answer each user provided.  you need to start with questions, left join to possible answers, then left join to the users answers.   Right joins would work in this place to but you have to figure out the right order.  To actually provide an answer I'd need to know what output you want.

Comment: What is the `group by` intending to accomplish?

Comment: @xQbert the problem is that those values are not actually null. User1 does have an answer for question2. The NULLs should be showing values because each of those users, in this example, has answered both question. (though the fake data I am showing might not actually reflect that)

Comment: @Matthew the `group by` is in there because I was getting multiple rows for each user... I will edit the question to show you.

Comment: So where the possible answer questions are not included in the aggregate function (group by) which of the multiple rows are you expecting them to come from? I might be missing something, but I would have expected your query to cause an error.

Comment: @Matthew I get what you're saying ... I guess I what i really need to somehow group the `LEFT JOINS` together so that the 1st and 2nd `LEFT JOIN` work together and the 3rd and 4th `LEFT JOIN` work together.

Comment: Also not sure you need a left join on answer to possible answer. This should be guaranteed a value here?

Comment: @Matthew Yes there will always be a possible_answer, if there is a user_answer value ... But then how do I join user_answer to possible_answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.name,

(SELECT pa1.text FROM possible_answer pa1, user_answer ua WHERE ua1.user_id = u.id AND ua1.answer_id = pa1.id AND pa1.question_id = 1 ORDER BY ua1.id DESC LIMIT 1) as 'Question1',

(SELECT pa2.text FROM possible_answer aa2, user_answer ua2 WHERE ua2.user_id = u.id AND ua2.answer_id = pa2.id AND pa.question_id = 2 ORDER BY ua.id DESC LIMIT 1) as 'Question2'

FROM user u  
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is closer to what your after...

```
Select UA.User_ID, PA.Question_ID, UA.Answer_ID, PA.Text
FROM Possible_Answer PA
LEFT JOIN user_Answer UA on PA.ID = UA.Answer_ID
ORDER BY PA.Question_ID, UA.User_ID
```

Returns all possible answers, the answer any user has provided to a question, and the text.  but it repeats question/answers for each user.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two possibilities, you can use this trick:

```
select ua.user_id,
       min(pa.text) as answer1,
       (case when min(pa.text) <> max(pa.text) then max(pa.text) end) as answer2
from possible_answer pa join
     user_answer ua
     on pa.id = ua.answer_id
group by ua.user_id
```

This loses the ordering based on the id in `user_answer`.  If the ordering is important, then take `min(id)` and `max(id)` and join back to `possible_answer` to get the right values.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is more of a hack but maybe this would work in a dynamic query:

```
select z.username, w.text as PA1, x.text as PA2
from user z 
join
    (select a.user_id, b.question_id, b.text, a.answer_id
    from
    user_answer a join possible_answer b on a.answer_id=b.id) as w
    on w.user_id=z.user_id 
    and w.question_id=1

join
    (select a.user_id, b.question_id, b.text, a.answer_id
    from
    user_answer a join possible_answer b on a.answer_id=b.id) as x
    on x.user_id=z.user_id 
    and x.question_id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with SQL Server so query write with syntax of SQL server. But I am sure same query will be work in MySQL too(may be with some changes).

For getting results as you want you need turn rows data to columns.
In SQL Server you can use CASE statement(Oracle DECODE, MySQL not sure but CASE too maybe)

Query is

```
SELECT u.Name, 
MAX(CASE WHEN pa1.QuestionID=1 THEN pa1.Text ELSE NULL END) AS Question1_answer,
MAX(CASE WHEN pa1.QuestionID=2 THEN pa1.Text ELSE NULL END) AS Question2_answer
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN UserAnswers ua1 ON ua1.UserID=u.ID
LEFT JOIN PossibleAnswers pa1 ON pa1.ID=ua1.AnswerID
GROUP BY u.Name
```

GROUPING By Name because we want questions in one row, 
so With grouping by Name and adding

```
MAX(...)
```

to Columns of answer we group answers of one user in one row

Here a link to SqlFiddler where I tried to create a same situation
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2357/10